# Python 3 How to return separate list from deriving quotient and remainder

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I need help to create two lists; one for quotient and one for remainder.

Eg. y = [20, 7, 88, 66, 18] and d = 9

After dividing the numbers from the list (y), I want to generate a single list to host quotient and remainder respectively; instead of adding more lists incrementally. Basically, I want the output code to generate like this:

This is the quotient.

[2, 0, 9, 7, 2]

This is the remainder.

[2, 7, 7, 3, 0]

Currently, my code makes it generate like this:

//(INPUT)//

```
#def calculate_quotient_and_remainder(y, d):

y = [20, 7, 88, 66, 18]
d = 9
r = []
q = []
print('This is the quotient.')

#def returnQuotient():

for i, one_a in enumerate(y):
    r.append(one_a // d) 
    print (r)
    
print('\n') 

#def returnRemainder():
print('This is the remainder.')
for j, one_b in enumerate(y): 
    q.append(one_b % d)
    print (q)
```

//(OUTPUT)//

This is the quotient.

[2]

[2, 0]

[2, 0, 9]

[2, 0, 9, 7]

[2, 0, 9, 7, 2]

This is the remainder.

[2]

[2, 7]

[2, 7, 7]

[2, 7, 7, 3]

[2, 7, 7, 3, 0]

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: please format your code

Comment: Use `print` only once after the loop ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `print` only once after each loop would solve your problem. Also, firstly, you can define a function:

```
def calculate_quotient_and_remainder(y, d):
    quotients = [] 
    remainders = [] 
    for num in y:
        quotients.append(num // d) # This is interger division. Use "int(num/d)" if you want.
        remainders.append(num % d)
        
    return quotients, remainders
```

Then, you can call and print the quotients and the remainders:

```
y = [20, 7, 88, 66, 18]
d = 9
q, r = calculate_quotient_and_remainder(y, d)
print('Quotients:', q)
print('Remainders:', r)
```

Output:

```
Quotients: [2, 0, 9, 7, 2]
Remainders: [2, 7, 7, 3, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension :

```py
y = [20, 7, 88, 66, 18] 
d = 9

quotient = [i//d for i in y]
reminder = [i%d for i in y]
```